# mysql query repeats the same resulting data rows multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have written a query which gives me the desired output but it repeats the output several time and as a results it affects the front end.Can anyone suggest a way to improve it.

query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  crm_support_inquiry 
  INNER JOIN crm_inquiry_perticipant 
    ON crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id = ? id 
  INNER JOIN crm_mailer_types 
    ON crm_support_inquiry.mailer_id = crm_mailer_types.mailer_id
```

And result is:
[image]

What changes is suppose to be done so that i get the output of only one company corresponding to the id provided.The mailertype and sent_on is repeated for all companies in crm_perticipant_inquiry.

Comment: Use GROUP BY to the query

Comment: @mahen3d that's a terrible advice

Comment: @user3300727: it means that your join conditions match more rows than you expect. For every row in right the row in the left duplicated exactly one time when you use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: you can use group by and unique

Comment: @Md.SharifulIslam and mahen3d Nope please see the usage of group by first if query doesn't need any aggregation then there is no sense to use group by

Comment: can you put sample record or screen shot.

Comment: so zerkms how can i deal with this?

Comment: try to put column name with alias in select statement.

Comment: isn't that adding " GROUP by sent_on,company" is going to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'distinct' keyword with your query,so you will not get repeat values

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the column names in your query and then select using distinct.

Distinct column1, column2, column3

Comment: i did the same. i will paste the query and result as well then u suggest me what i am suppose to do

Comment: Please mark the duplicate rows, I don't see any duplicate row.

Comment: The thing is my query is going wrong somewhere. The type_name and sent_on repeats with the different company names. where as i want the type_name and sent_on details of only 1 company associated to the id 28.

Comment: You may not understand exactly your requirement or you may have wrongly designed your table structure or you have wrong entry in your tables. Look into your records in each table and understand the structure very well. Finally if you didn't do it upload your tables at some where so others could easily access it and help you in querying the result.